Handle huge number of index in Firestore queries
Here is my code:
Query query = firestore.collection("users")
        .document(myUserID)
        .collection("unseen_profiles")
        .whereEqualTo("country", myProfileCountryFilter);


if (!myProfileGenderFilter.isEmpty() && !myProfileGenderFilter.equalsIgnoreCase("everyone")) {
    query = query.whereEqualTo("gender", myProfileGenderFilter);

}


if (heightFilterOn) {

    query = query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("height", minimumHeight);
}

if (weightFilterOn) {
    query = query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("weight", maximumWeight);
}

if (customAgeFilterOn) {
     query = query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("age", minimumAge)
            .whereLessThanOrEqualTo("age", maximumAge);
}

if (lookingForFilterOn) {
      query = query.whereArrayContainsAny("looking_for", lookingForArray);
}

if (personalityTypeFilterOn) {

         query = query.whereIn("personality_type", personalityTypeList);
}

if (homeCountryFilterOn) {
       query = query.whereEqualTo("home_country", homeCountryFilter);


}

// Add orderBy for timestamp
query = query.orderBy("timestamp");


// Configure the adapter options
PagingConfig config = new PagingConfig(
        10, // PageSize
        5, // PrefetchDistance
        false // EnablePlaceholders
);


FirestorePagingOptions<DataModel> options = new FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<DataModel>()
        .setLifecycleOwner(this) // Lifecycle owner
        .setQuery(query, config, DataModel.class) // Query and the model class
        .build();

Now when different conditions satisfy, every time the app crashes & ask to create an index. But considering combination of the above conditions, if I have to create index for all of them then a huge number of index needs to be created.
I heard that if I need to create many indexes then maybe I am not using query efficiently or maybe I need to optimize the data structure. But in my case I don't find any other viable options to achieve desired functionality with the query. Am I missing anything? If I am not missing anything then how can I manage creating such large of indexes with time efficiency? Is there any way I can automate creating index when the query requires without the app crashing or query failing?


Now when different conditions are satisfied, every time the app crashes & asks to create an index.

That's because all those queries require an index.

But considering the combination of the above conditions, if I have to create an index for all of them then a huge number of indexes needs to be created.

Yes, you have to create an index for each combination. So as long as you stay below the maximum limitation which is 200, when you have not enabled billing for your Google Cloud project, then there will be no problems. If you enable billing for your Google Cloud project, then the maximum number is 500. If these 500 indexes are not enough, then you can contact support to request an increase to this limit.

I heard that if I need to create many indexes then maybe I am not using the query efficiently or maybe I need to optimize the data structure.

If you need to create many indexes, it doesn't mean that you're not using the query efficiently. It simply means that you need to filter the data using many combinations, which is fine given the fact that you have so many fields that you need to filter on.

If I am not missing anything then how can I manage to create such large of indexes with time efficiency?

Yes, you can deploy the Firestore indexes using the Firebase CLI.

Yes, you can deploy the Firestore indexes using the Firebase CLI. Can I pre determine how many indexes do I need for all of the combination of conditions for my query?  If so , then how?

Once you know all query combinations, you can then determine (calculate) how many indexes you actually need. Using the Firebase CLI it's a more efficient way of creating the indexes rather than crashing the app at every single combination of your queries.

While each query needs to be backed by an index (as Alex said), you may not need a separate index for each query. It may be able to use multiple smaller indexes for a single query, by merging their contents. As explained in the documentation on using merged indexes:

Although Cloud Firestore uses an index for every query, it does not necessarily require one index per query. For queries with multiple equality (==) clauses and, optionally, an orderBy clause, Cloud Firestore can re-use existing indexes. Cloud Firestore can merge the indexes for simple equality filters to build the composite indexes needed for larger equality queries.
You can reduce indexing costs by identifying situations where you can take advantage of index merging...

I recommend reading the entire documentation section, as it explains in more detail and shows an example.
Queries executed on multiple merged indexes are usually slower than those for which an exact composite index exists though, so you'll have to trade off performance versus the number of indexes (and their cost).

1000 index read costs 1 read operation, right? And concerning merged indexes, I have already added  composite indexes for 256 combinations of the query in firebase console. Also I need better performance anyways.
